# Swift 3 - Android Equivalent Of Getting Past 12 Months Using Calendar Class

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, nsdate, nscalendar

In `Android`, I'm able to generate labels for my line chart for the past 12 months including this month.

In my `TimeDateHelper` class:

```
public static DateFormat getMonthYearChartLabelFormat() {
    DateFormat monthYearChartLabelFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM ''yy", Locale.US);
    monthYearChartLabelFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
    return monthYearChartLabelFormat;
}
```

In my other `LineChartActivity` class:

```
private void setUpMonthLabels() {
    this.labels = new ArrayList<>();
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
    cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, -11);
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        this.labels.add(TimeDateHelper.getMonthYearChartLabelFormat().format(cal.getTime()));
        cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
    }
}
```

The `enumerateDates` method in `Swift 3`'s `Calendar` class is way too confusing. I don't know whether to use that or something else. All I want is the past 12 months including this month. For example, this month is December, so the output would be:

```
Jan '16
Feb '16
Mar '16
Apr '16
May '16
Jun '16
Jul '16
Aug '16
Sep '16
Oct '16
Nov '16
Dec '16
```

How can I get this done with Swift 3?

**** PROGRESS ****

So far, I have some formatting set up:

```
let dateFormatter: DateFormatter = {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current
    return formatter
}()

func getMonthYearChartLabelString(fromDate date: Date) -> String {
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = DateFormatter.dateFormat(fromTemplate: "MMM ''yy", options: 0, locale: Locale(identifier: "en-US"))
    return dateFormatter.string(from: date)
}
```

The apostrophe doesn't work for some reason tho (ex. it shows Dec 16 when it should show Dec '16).

Comment: Do you want the output as strings or date objects?

Comment: Strings, I'll edit the post with the formatting I've put in so far

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my first stab at it.

```
import Foundation

var past12Months: [String] {
    let today = Date()
    let dates = (-12...0).flatMap{ Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .month, value: $0, to: today)}

    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM ''yy"

    let strings = dates.map{ dateFormatter.string(from: $0)! } //TODO: add error handling here
    return strings
}

print(past12Months)
```

Comment: Weird, when I change it to using my dateFormatter, it prints empty strings

Comment: Is it possibly because of time zone?

Comment: @Rafi Ah yes, silent failure strikes again. `flapMap` filters `nil` results. It's better to use `let strings = dates.map{ dateFormatter.string(from: $0)! }` instead, so your app crashes when the date formatter fails

Comment: Nice. One more thing I'm wondering is why does your formatter work with an apostrophe but mind does not?! That's so weird!

Comment: Either way I'm marking this as correct because it's the cleanest solution. I've never seen that "flatMap" method before!

Comment: Have you used map before?

Comment: A couple times when I was reading the Swift 3 book but I don't remember the flatMap one

Comment: `flatMap` is like `map`, but it flattens the result before adding it to the output array. For example `[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]].flatMap{ $0 }` produces `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`. It's also useful for unwrapping all optionals in an array, and weeding out the `nil`s. The downside, as you saw, is that this is a fail-silent approach, which can produce hard to catch bugs

Answer (score 2):

You can use Calendar to get array of last 12 months  month+Year value.
here is Swift 3 equivalent of what you have done in Android:

```
 let cal = Calendar.current
    var date = cal.startOfDay(for: Date())
    var lables = [String]()
    let dateFormatter: DateFormatter = DateFormatter()

    let months = dateFormatter.shortMonthSymbols

    for i in 1 ... 12 {
        let  mon =  cal.component(.month, from: date)
        let month = months?[mon-1] //as! String // month - from your date components
        let year = String(cal.component(Calendar.Component.yearForWeekOfYear, from: date))
        let index1 = year.index(year.endIndex, offsetBy: -2)
        let strDate =  month!  + " '" + year.substring(from: index1);
        lables.append(strDate)
        date = cal.date(byAdding: .month, value: -1, to: date)!
    }
    print(lables)
```

You will get required values in labels array